# How to disable Copy & Define UIMenuItems of UIMenuController in UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I am implementing custom `UIMenuController` and trying to figure out. How can I legally disable "Copy" and "Define" UIMenuItems of `UIMenuController` in `UITextfield`? Textfield is not editable. I tried to disable "Copy" using:

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
   if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}


- (IBAction)tapTextViewGesture:(id)sender {

  UIMenuItem *myItem1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"myItem1" action:@selector(myItem1Pressed:)];
  UIMenuItem *myItem2 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"myItem2" action:@selector(myItem2Pressed:)];
  UIMenuItem *myItem3 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"myItem3" action:@selector(myItem3Pressed:)];

    // Access the application's shared menu
    UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

    [menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:myItem1,myItem2,myItem3, nil]];

    CGRect menuRect = CGRectMake(20, 50, 200, 0);


    // Show the menu from the cursor's position
    [menu setTargetRect:menuRect inView:self.view];


    [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}
```

But the menu is still showing "Copy" and "Define" `UIMenuItems`. How can I disable them, leaving only my items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally solved it by subclassing `UITextView` (created custom class for it) and just added

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{

    if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

inside of .m file of my custom TextView subclass.

After that "Copy" doesn't appear any more, with or without `[menu update]`;

Comment: How you achieved this? Xcode says it's a private method and it cannot be deleted from menu (actually it deleted it, but when I tried to archieve project and upload it to appstore - i just can't - error popped up and sayed I used Appe's private method where I shouldn't ) .

Comment: this code is not working for me. I tried in iOS 9.1, 8.3. its still shoing the Paste option. Please help me with any other solution

Answer (score 5):

Implement this instance method in viewController.m:

```
**- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if ([_targetTextField isFirstResponder]) {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
        }];
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}**
```

This method checks if targeted text field is the first responder or not. If it is, NSOperationQueue creates a separate thread for sharedMenuController operation, set its visibility and animation as no so that it couldn't work for copy, paste,etc. The return statement calls UIResponder's canPerformAction method to inform for the same to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2.** && **Xcode 10** that works for me:

```
public extension UITextView {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        // Requested action to prevent:
        guard action != #selector(copy(_:)) else { return false }      // disabling copy

        // Further actions to prevent:
        // guard action != #selector(cut(_:)) else { return false }    // disabling cut
        // guard action.description != "_share:" else { return false } // disabling share
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

In order to make this work you must create a subclass of `UITextField`/`UITextView` and make sure to call super on `super.canPerformAction(_:withSender:)`!

Comment: without subclassing is it possible?

Comment: @karthikeyan yes it should be possible to put the code into an extension.

Comment: do you have sample?

Comment: @karthikeyan If I understand it correctly, you want to disable all actions correctly? If so, just replace the code in `canPerformAction:withSender:` with `return false`. My code only disables the copy action.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making a class by subclassing `UITextField` class and overriding its `canPerformAction::` method.

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    // Returning 'NO' here disables all actions on textfield
    return NO;
}
```