# How can i prevent copy button from appearing when select a text in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I don't want the Copy / Define button to appear when select a text.
How can i do that in objective c ?

**UPDATE**: i want to do that in UIWebView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747140/how-to-disable-copy-define-uimenuitems-of-uimenucontroller-in-uitextfield-ios

Comment: i want to do that in web view not text field

Comment: `canPerformAction:withSender:` is in `UIResponder` which is a common ancestor for both `UITextView` and `UIWebView`

Comment: i did that with web view but only Define button disappeared and Copy button still appears when select a text.

Answer (score 1):

> The easiest way to disable pasteboard operations is to create a subclass of UITextView that overrides the canPerformAction:withSender: method to return NO for actions that you don't want to allow:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Also see [UIResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html)

Answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview) posted by [rpetrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4007/rpetrich)

Comment: this for textview but i want to do that in web view

Answer (score 0):

Here are all actions sent to `canPerformAction:withSender:

```
cut:
copy:
select:
selectAll:
paste:
delete:
_promptForReplace:
_transliterateChinese:
_showTextStyleOptions:
_define:
_addShortcut:
_accessibilitySpeak:
_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:
_accessibilityPauseSpeaking:
makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:
makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:
```

so what you need to remove Copy/Define is the following

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copy:))
        return NO;
    if (action == @selector(_define:))
        return NO;

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```